# Convert object to CSV and then compress without touching physical storage

Tags: c#, csv, gzip

### Scenario

I have a object that I convert to a flat CSV and then compress and upload to a filestore.

I could easily do this by following the below steps.

1. Convert object to CSV file.
2. Compress file
3. Upload file.

### However

I do not want the penalty that comes with touching physical storage so would like to do all this in memory.

### Current Incorrect Implementation

1. Convert object to CSV byte array
2. Compress byte array
3. Upload byte array to file store

### Problem

What i'm essentially doing is compressing a byte array and uploading that. which is obviously wrong. (Because when the compressed Gzip file is uncompressed, it contains a byte array of the csv and not the actual csv itself.)

Is it possible to create a file like "file.csv" in memory and then compress that in memory, instead of compressing a byte array?

The problem I'm having is it would seem I can only name the file and specify its extension when saving to a physical location.

### Code Example of Current Implementation

```
public byte[] Example(IEnumerable<object> data)
    {
        // Convert Object to CSV and write to byte array.
        byte[] bytes = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csv.WriteRecords(data);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        //Compress byte array
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
            zipStream.Close();

            var gzipByteArray =  resultStream.ToArray();
            //Upload to AzureStorage
            new AzureHelper().UploadFromByteArray(gzipByteArray, 0, gzipByteArray.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the necessary file details in the request as metadata

Comment: Show the code for the current implementation

Comment: @Nkosi That would be great if I could do that, what do you mean "in the request" though.

Comment: Why is compressing a byte array "obviously wrong"?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Because when the compressed Gzip file is uncompressed, it contains a byte array of the csv and now the actual csv itself.

Comment: What is the difference? What is "the actual csv itself"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `Stream` you use for the upload in a [`GZipStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream), write your CSV to that, and the then you'll have uploaded the compressed CSV.